# Paper thickness (weight) to use for card tabs/dividers?

Tags: dominion, storage

I'm planning on building a custom storage solution for my Dominion cards (to fit the expansions in the main box with the base set).  For part of this, I will need to cut some tabs similar to the ones in [this photo](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/image/843042/dominion).  What weight of paper should I look for?  I assume the thicker the better, but if the best a store has is, say, 60# paper, should I hold out for something better at another place?  Are there other issues to consider with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main consideration in my experience (many, many Magic cards) is that the thickness/weight of the paper doesn't matter as much as the stiffness and the smoothness of it.  you'll want something that slides out easily, so the cards can be retrieved without losing the divider in the box.  The stiffness is important because anything too flexible will tend to fray the tab portion.  Since dominion is a standard card size, I'd highly suggest plastic dividers, which can be obtained for as little as $0.10 each at various stores.